# Merging entities in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

what is the best way to do this:

I have some entities stored as Hibernate entities and they contain some fields that needs to be unique for single row. So when i create another entity with that set of fields equal to already persisted one, I want to override old record with new, else create new record.

What would be the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the primary key of your entity, you can use `session.merge(entity)` or `session.saveOrUpdate(entity)`

If it is another unique constraint you'd have to handle this manually - first try to find an entity with that value (with a query), and if it doesn't exist, save the new one, otherwise, transfer all the fields (except for the primary key)

Comment: So I should have somehow make composite key from columns whose combinations has to be unique?

Comment: Yes. There's the `@IdClass` annotation. And also `@EmbeddedId`

Comment: I wouldn't change the ID just to implement this. Hibernate recommends single-column surrogate primary keys. Putting several columns, potentially mutable, in a primary key will cause more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

use .merge() instead.

From http://www.stevideter.com/2008/12/07/saveorupdate-versus-merge-in-hibernate/:

> Theory: If we then modify our detached object and want to update it, we have to reattach the object. During that reattachment process, Hibernate will check to see if there are any other copies of the same object. If it finds any, it has to tell us it doesn’t know what the “real” copy is any more. Perhaps other changes were made to those other copies that we expect to be saved, but Hibernate doesn’t know about them, because it wasn’t managing them at the time.
>
> Rather than save possibly bad data, Hibernate tells us about the problem via the NonUniqueObjectException.